# Rails 4 - how to load print style sheet last with bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I have a rails app at 4.1.5. There are some score sheet pages which need printing and which need to printed at an exact font size and td border thickness (thin). I am using the bootstrap-sass gem.

I have just updated my code to bootstrap 3 and now find that bootstrap is interfering with my score sheet css. What is my best strategy?

1. Place my scoresheet css file in either lib/assets or vendor/assets. I have read that there is a descending load order with vendor/assets loaded last but can't confirm if that's true.
2. Put my score sheet css (or sass) into my bootstrap overrides css after the @import bootstrap directive.
3. Remove require_tree from my application.css and require each file explicitly in order.  I understand require_tree will load files in random order.
4. None of the above?

Answer (score 0):

`require_tree` will load alphabetically.  You could prefix each file with a number, but that's not my recommendation.

You can explicitly require files, then follow that with a `require_tree`, which is a catch-all for the rest, which I recommend.

Regarding order, if you want to affect all sass variable based items such as font-size across the entire site:

1. declare values for matching variables (see bootstrap/variables.scss)
2. import bootstrap
3. require specifics, then catch-all with require_tree